# Converting heic/heif to jpg in react native (or nodejs)

Tags: node.js, react-native, sharp, heic, heif

I have a react native app on ios where users can upload photos. I resize these photos server-side with [sharp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sharp). The problem is:
the HEIC/HEIF-files from ios are not compatible with sharp. I get the following error:

```
¡Error: source: bad seek to 2808991
heif: Unsupported feature: Unsupported codec (4.3000)
¿
```

Is there a way to get a JPG version of the photo? It's also ok if I have to convert the file to jpg on the server, but how can I detect the codec of the image (so that only HEIC/HEIF images are converted, and not jpg or png)?

How can I convert them client side or server side?

Answer (score 0):

[React Native Image Resizer](https://github.com/bamlab/react-native-image-resizer) can perform HEIC to jpeg compression on the app. It's a native module so you'll have to build a development client if you're using expo.